# If $AX=B$, does $\det(AX)=\det(B)$?

Tags: linear-algebra, determinant

If $AX=B$, does $\det(AX)=\det(B)$?

I apologize if I'm doing something wrong here or if this has already been asked. This is my first time posting here and I couldn't find this question.

I'm using Gilbert Strang's *Introduction to Linear Algebra* for my linear algebra class, and in section 5.3 he portrays the key idea of Cramer's Rule as this:

$\begin{bmatrix}\\&A&\\\\\end{bmatrix}$$\begin{bmatrix}x_1 & 0 & 0\\ x_2 & 1 & 0\\ x_3 & 0 & 1\end{bmatrix}$ = $\begin{bmatrix} \textbf{b}_\textbf{1} & a_{12} & a_{13} \\ \textbf{b}_\textbf{2} & a_{22} & a_{23} \\ \textbf{b}_\textbf{3} & a_{32} & a_{33}\end{bmatrix}$ = $B_1,$

where $A$ is a $3\times 3$ matrix. Then he says to "take the determinants of the 3 matrices to find $x_1$":

$(\det A)(x_1) = (\det B_1)$, or $x_1 = \frac{\det B_1}{\det A}.$

Can you do that? If you multiply two $n\times n$ matrices to get $B$, can you take the determinants of both sides without changing the equality? I get the feeling the answer to this is extremely obvious, but I don't know how to prove it.

Comment: If $Y = Z$ then $\det(Y) = \det(Z)$.  Note that $x_1$ is precisely the determinant of your second matrix.  (Expand upon the first row.)

Comment: This also assumes you are cool with the multiplicative property of determinants: $\det(AX) = \det(A) \det(X)$..

Comment: @Randall Thanks, I don't know how I missed that. Should I delete this question? It seems pretty useless.

Comment: I don't know:  there's some value in explaining precisely the argument that Axler is giving.

Comment: Sorry, Strang.  (I should have known it's not Axler since determinants are being used.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The equation $AX=B$ says that $AX$ and $B$ are two expressions for the same matrix, so of course $f(AX)=f(B)$ for any operation $f$. It's the same thing on both sides.

As pointed out in the comments, the linear algebra fact being used is that the determinant is multiplicative, so that $\det(AX)=\det(A)\det(X)$.